# Django AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model 'powerlistapp.appuser' that has not been installed ERROR

Tags: python, django-models, django-migrations, abstractuser

i have model as in below

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class AppUser(AbstractUser):
    user_department = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    user_group_email = models.EmailField(max_length=100)
    user_company_id = models.CharField(max_length=8)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.username} {self.last_name} {self.user_department}"

class PowerCustomer(models.Model):  
    customer_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    customer_surname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    customer_birth_date = models.DateField()
    customer_phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    customer_email = models.EmailField()
    customer_origin_country = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    customer_has_high_priority = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    customer_creation_date = models.DateField()
    customer_loyalty_membership_number = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    customer_job_type = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    customer_description = models.CharField(max_length=370)
    user = models.ForeignKey(AppUser, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='power_customers')
    

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.customer_name} {self.customer_surname} {self.customer_job_type} {self.customer_description}"
```

and i have properly  configured installed apps as in below

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'powerlistapp',
]
```

and i have  configured my Auth user as in below

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'powerlistapp.AppUser',,
```

and i receive this error when i want to make my migrations.

```
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model 'powerlistapp.appuser' that has not been installed
```

i have deleted my database and  delete all migrations and re run python3 manage.py makemigrations. etc

Comment: remove the commas at the end of `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'powerlistapp.AppUser',,.

Comment: thank you for your advise, i have removed nothing changed after that i have applied the sollution in below that i have explained.

Answer (score 0):

to solve the problem i have deleted AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'powerlistapp.AppUser'  from my settings. py and after that i made migrations  problem solved and after that i have repaste the related code to settings.py
this works for me i hope it work for all.

Answer (score -1):

Try to run in your terminal:

```
python manage.py makemigrations powerlistapp
```

and then

```
python manage.py migrate
```

If this solution does not help, could you please send your project structure (dir and file names)

Comment: hello this is not about folder structure. it is  a bug  from django. also as i have mentioned in the text i have already made migrations and remove it many times. but thanks for your kindness and help.